# Get the specific value from an array of object based on ID

Tags: angular, typescript

```
let a=[{'id': '1234', 'name':'Server 1'}, {'id': '2262', 'name':'Server 2'}];

id='1234'

attachmentName: string;
```

I want to get the name, based on the specific ID.

Result: attachmentName= 'Server 1' based on id=1234

I tried a.filter, but it does not give me proper result. Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you looking for is find() method which return you an array item which match your condition.

```
let a = [{'id': '1234', 'name':'Server 1'}, {'id': '2262', 'name':'Server 2'}];
let yourWantedName = a.find(element => {
  return element.id === '1234';
}).name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to use `Array.find` instead of `Array.filter`. `Array.filter` will return an array of matched results, whereas `Array.find` will return the first result found. Since you're trying to find something by `id`, you can do the following:

```js
let a=[{'id': '1234', 'name':'Server 1'}, {'id': '2262', 'name':'Server 2'}];

id='1234'

const id1234 = a.find(o => o.id === id);
console.log(id1234);
```

[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

really filter didn't work? hmmm. How about this. Have you tried using `find` method?

```
let a=[{'id': '1234', 'name':'Server 1'}, {'id': '2262', 'name':'Server 2'}];

const res = a.find( (item) => item.id === '1234' );

console.log(res)
```

Note: that `find` will return the first item that it will hit after that the loop goes out. you can find more about [find method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)